# Debugging ELECTRON.NET app from VISUALSTUDIO 2019 - NETCORE 3.1

Tags: debugging, electron, electron.net

Im having a hard time trying to debug an ELECTRON.NET APP using visual studio 2019.

It is a ASP.NET CORE 3.1 MVC with RAZOR.

The app runs fine in ELECTRON, however when I attach the process to visual studio, the symbols are never loaed.

[image: No Symbols Image]

I´ve tried all the possible opened electron process and no one made that work.

Is that really possible?

```
electronize tool = 8.31.1
ELECTRONNet.API = 8.31.1
NET.CORE 3.1
VISUAL STUDIO 2019 - 16.5.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your electron.manifest file, and find the executable property

[image]

Then attach the process that has the exact same name
[image]